# Execution of Group By - single vs two iteration

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, grouping

When we perform `groupBy` in spark, does it bring the entire grouped data to a single partition/executor or does it perform initial grouping on whichever partition the data is present and finally bring all unique groups from each partition to a single partition for final group?

For example: If we have 100 records(just for illustration) having two fields `city` and `country` and 5 groups based on city and country i.e. each city, and country have 20 records on different partitions.
When we perform `group by city, country` does Spark perform 1st level grouping at individual partition level and later perform the final group on a single partition by bringing all related city and country groups or does Spark perform just a single level of grouping by shuffling all related groups instead of two-level grouping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark generally wants to minimize data movement during shuffling, so it will perform "group by" first on the partitions and then shuffle the data to bring related groups together again.

Example: When you perform `groupBy("city", "country")` it will shuffle within the partitions(intra) and then inter partitions to bring together (same city and country) together in the same partition for the final movement.

Though there are other factors this depends on.

Comment: got it. So when we have city,country,population and need to compute total_population group by city,country, then does spark (1) list individual values for each group within each partition ie. city,1country1,<val1,val2..valn> and finally passes/shuffles each group value to final group by to compute total_population or (2) compute total population for each group within each partition ie. city,1country1,<total_population_per_partition>, then shuffle each grouped value to single partition based on group, to compute total population based on values from all groups together ?

Comment: compute for each group and then for all later if I am not wrong.